# Translate tweets to English

Tags: python, tweets, google-translation-api

I have a few tweets in German for which I need to compute polarity. TextBlob doesn't seem to work straight away on German tweets:

```
tweets
Liebes #GameTwo Team. 
Ich hoffe sehr das ihr weiterhin 150 Folgen draufsetzt auf die bestehenden 150. 
Die Reise hat bis hierhin sehr viel Spa√ü gemacht und wird weiterhin so viel Spa√ü machen. 


from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
translator = Translator()

 df['English'] = 

 df['tweets'].apply(translator.translate,src='de',dest='en').apply(getattr,args=('text',))
 df
```

But I get the following error :

```
 JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Can somebody help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran below code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
translator = Translator()

tweets = [("Liebes"), ("Ich hoffe sehr das ihr weiterhin 150 Folgen draufsetzt auf die bestehenden 150"), ("Die Reise hat bis hierhin sehr viel Spa√ü gemacht und wird weiterhin so viel Spa√ü machen")]

df = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns = ['german'])

df['English'] = df['german'].apply(translator.translate,src='de',dest='en').apply(getattr,args=('text',))

df
```

And it worked well for me with the following output:

[image]

Let me know if it still doesn't works for you.